# Problem with z-index in Internet Explorer 7

Tags: css, xhtml

i have a testcase [here](http://www.webdevout.net/test?01o).

What I want to achieve is, that the blue parent element with its green child element wraps around the red element like a paper-clip. As you can see in all modern browsers this works very well - but in IE7 the green element stays in the background.

Is there a solution how I can achieve this in IE7?

EDIT: It is essential, that the green element remains as a child element of the blue one because the blue element will be animated which also takes effect on the green elements width an position.

Comment: It looks the same in IE7 and IE8. Are you counting *IE9* as your "modern version" IE browser? Edit: Actually, other than the opacity, it appears to look in the same in IE7 as in Firefox/Chrome.

Comment: Actually it looks fine in IE8 (I dont have IE9), Firefox 4/Chrome/Opera 11 -> the blue elm is behind the red elm and the green elm is on top. I use IE8's compatibility mode to emulate an IE7 render behavior.

Comment: *I'm sure* that test case has changed since I looked at it before. There was no transparency in IE before.. Well, I can see the problem you're having now.

Answer (score 0):

Add `position:relative;` to the CSS where z-index is declared. It works in most cases.

In your case it would be

```
  #middle-container {
      width: 250px;
      height: 300px;
      background: red;
      left: 100px;
      top: 20px;
      z-index: 2;
      position: relative; /* added row to make z-index work */
      opacity: .9;
  }

  #container-behind {
      width: 220px;
      height: 110px;
      padding-left: 70px;
      background: blue;
      top: 80px;
      left: 320px;
      z-index: 1;
      position: relative; /* added row to make z-index work */
  }
```

Comment: As you can see in the first line of the CSS #middle-container and #container-behind already have position:absolute; which unfortunately I can not change to relative because the elements will be positioned inside a bigger container and will be animated with jQuery :(

Answer (score 0):

This works in IE7

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dTJ4d/1

Demo 2: http://jsfiddle.net/dTJ4d/2

```
<div id="middle-container">    
    #middle-container
    <div id="container-behind">
        #container-behind
    </div>
    <div id="inner-behind">
        #inner-behind
    </div>
</div>
```

```
DIV
{
    padding: 10px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
#middle-container
{
    width: 250px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #FF0000;
    left: 100px;
    top: 20px;
}
#container-behind
{
    width: 220px;
    height: 110px;
    padding-left: 70px;
    background: #0000FF;
    top: 80px;
    left: 70px;
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
}
#inner-behind
{
    width: 210px;
    padding-left: 70px;
    background: #80E64D;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 75px;
    left: 50px;
}
```

EDIT: cleaned up a few lines of code

Comment: hi wdm, thanks, but this is not what i need. I just edited the post:

It is essential, that the green element remains as a child element of the blue one because the blue element will be animated which also takes effect on the green elements width an position.

so, if the width or the position of the blue div changes the green divs width also changes and its position must not change inside the blue element.